# What is the name of this mosaic technique?

Tags: illustration, technique

Does this mosaic technique have a name? I want to learn how to create images like this:

Marquee of InDesign CS6:
[image: Marquee of InDesign CS6]

And random image of a girl I found on the web:

[image: Girl]

It combines many almost random but thematically or stylistically similar images, newspaper clippings, letters and snippets of text, etc to create one rough, chaotic, energetic image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd call it a bricolage.

> In the visual arts bricolage is the construction or creation of a work from a diverse range of things that happen to be available, or a work created by such a process. The term is borrowed from the French word bricolage.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bricolage

Other names it may be known by:

- Merz
- Polystylism
- Collage
- Assemblage

Answer (score 0):

**Mosaic** or **collage** are as good a term as any. You could also try **deconstructivist**.

Try a search and see what you find.